# Not connecting to mLab but connecting locally via mongod

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, localhost

I am trying to connect to this remote DB

```
mongoURL = mongodb://blahuser:blahpassword@ds019053.mlab.com:19053/my-app
```

and I get this error:

```
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds019053.mlab.com:19053] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to ds019053.mlab.com:19053 timed out]
```

I also ran: `mongo ds019053.mlab.com:19053` and got this error:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.4
connecting to: ds019053.mlab.com:19053
2017-05-26T10:24:47.108-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 54.198.224.164:19053 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2017-05-26T10:24:47.109-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server ds019053.mlab.com:19053, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

However, When I run `mongod` I successfully connect to my local mongoDB and my app loads.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You can run mkdir -p /data/db from anywhere.  It's going to create a root data directory and then db underneath it.  If you cd to the root you will be able to see it.

Comment: Ah found it. thanks you. but any idea what's wrong with mLab?

Comment: It's possible that the mLab URI isn't accessible on your local network. Try going through the following connection troubleshooting steps:http://docs.mlab.com/connecting/#help